# How do you sum up torques for a macroscopic object

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque, moment-of-inertia

Torque is measured about a point. But angular momentum for some object is measured around an axis. This doesn't make sense to me as in for example, a cylinder. If there are multiple tangent forces on the surface of the cylinder, what point do you choose in order to calculate total rate of change in angular momentum. If we pick multiple points, why is this a valid calculation?

Comment: How do i work out the torque on a cylinder where forces act at different points?

Answer (score 2):

Both torque and angular momentum are measured relative to a (origin) point of your choice. If you have several forces acting at different points, you add the different torques, all measured relative to the same origin point.